# HTML annotation errors in Eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have a website that I've sifted through all of the errors on and fixed but now I just have a bunch of HTML errors that Eclipse is screaming at me about.  The website for as far as I can see is in working order. It was originally written in XHTML 1.0 Strict. So my assumption is that Eclipse is saying that this code is not compatible with HTML 5, but since it's forced to be downgraded that it still works. What do you think?

```
<h3 class="create-listing-details-expander ui-corner-all">Practice Areas <span style="display:block;float:right;">3 of 4</span></h3>

<div class="create-listing-details input">
    <div class="input-side-by-sides fixed-width-200"><label><input type="checkbox" name="profile[options][practice_areas][0]" value="Administrative"  ( < NEW-PROFILE-PRACTICE-AREAS-0 > ) />Administrative</label></div>
    <div class="input-side-by-sides fixed-width-200"> <label><input type="checkbox" name="profile[options][practice_areas][1]" value="Agriculture"  ( < NEW-PROFILE-PRACTICE-AREAS-1 > ) />Agriculture</label></div>
    <div class="input-side-by-sides fixed-width-200"> <label><input type="checkbox" name="profile[options][practice_areas][2]" value="Antitrust"  ( < NEW-PROFILE-PRACTICE-AREAS-2 > ) />Antitrust</label></div>
    <div class="input-side-by-sides fixed-width-200"> <label><input type="checkbox" name="profile[options][practice_areas][3]" value="Appellate Practice"  ( < NEW-PROFILE-PRACTICE-AREAS-3 > ) />Appellate Practice</label></div>
    [ectra......]
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Here are the type of errors it's throwing:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>
> - Undefined attribute name (().
> - Invalid text string (< NEW-PROFILE-PRACTICE-AREAS-0 > ) />Administrative).
> - Tag (input) should be an empty-element tag.
> - Start tag () not closed properly, expected '>'.
> - Invalid character used in text string (< NEW-PROFILE-PRACTICE-AREAS-0 > ) />Administrative).

Comment: Well, there are these elements `( < NEW-PROFILE-PRACTICE-AREAS-0 > )` which are not valid content of a HTML-tag nor are they valid attributes. You also don't need a closing `/` on `<input>`-elements anymore. The rest looks fine.

Comment: And this has always been invalid HTML as well as invalid XHTML. Nothing to do with the fact that Eclipse is now HTML5 compatible.